# TTY login problem

Tags: lubuntu, login, tty

OS: Lubuntu 16.04

I recently had a problem with login to TTY (1-6). When I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after the username a newline character seems to repeat every 3 seconds or so.

Halfway through typing the password, a newline occurs and I get Incorrect Login. This continues to repeat a newline every few seconds until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Has anyone come across this before? It does not happen in a Terminal window or GUI login, only when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: What kernel are you using? Is this a 32 bit system?   See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1815122?comments=all